# Could XOR-swap cause an overflow and does it work with floats?

Tags: c, swap, xor

Let's say I want to swap variables `a` and `b` using XOR-swap.

```
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

Could this cause an overflow, and can I swap those numbers when they are of type float or double?

Comment: It can cause `int` overflow and does not work with FP types.

Comment: Does this really need to be a SO question? If you're unsure, you could just [test](https://ideone.com/6vZN4z)

Comment: You can XOR and type as a bunch of bits if you cast it to an integer of the same width and then cast it back.

Comment: It's neat trick but I don't see any advantage over using a temporary variable, except perhaps when you have 0 memory available. In fact, your way needs 6 reads and 3 writes, but the temporay way needs 3 reads and 3 writes.

Comment: @Corey:  The problem with just testing is that you could miss the counter examples.  Even if you stumble across something that would be undefined behavior, the compiler you're testing with could end up doing the expected thing.

Comment: @JoshHomann: If you cast a float to an integer, you get an integer with (approximately) the same value, not the bit pattern of the float.

Comment: you're right you have to cast it to a void and then to an Int or use a union that views the same memory for the float and int.

Comment: The bitwise operators are applicable only to integral types; they cannot be applied directly to `float` or `double`.  They could, in principle, be used *indirectly* to swap FP values, but conforming code for doing so would be much more complex than simply swapping in the conventional way, via a temporary variable.  Unlike the shift operators, however, the bitwise operators have defined behavior for all integral operands.  They may produce a trap value, but they will not cause overflow in the sense of UB-inducing overflow.

Comment: @WeatherVane: So that means using a temporary variable is much faster?

Comment: @Xeneda it might all be done in registers though.

Comment: Compilers are *very good* at eliminating temporary variables.  That's a big chunk of the compiler's job--doing flow analysis.  Using 80s era hacks like an XOR swap are not only unnecessary (long ago, when computers had a small number of registers, it was ok) but are actually detrimental to performance.  The XOR swap introduces data dependencies which can stall your pipeline, and it sabotages the compiler's ability to do certain types of optimizations.

Comment: @chux: Do you have a reference to the standard saying it can generate overflow at all?

Comment: @Xeneda: Leave such optimisations to your compiler. A good compiler might even use the xor-approach if it detects the swap pattern with temporarily variable. This all depends on the target platform, situation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will have undefined behaviour; it could cause any number of problems.

Even assuming you found a reliable way to get the bit representation of the floating point number as an integer of the same size, you might still manage to create a floating point trap representation when you do the intermediate XOR, so storing that into the floating point value could be problematic.

The XOR hack is passé. Use a temporary. Your computer probably has a *lot* of floating point registers, and using them is really fast.